# Google Maps - Scraping KML / extract overlays data ( coordinates )

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay, gis, kml

I would like to understand how to scrape / extract KML data from a google map overlay.

I have been trying for last few month without success. I did try using `fiddler` and my console developer tools to look into the site's source code.
I went through almost every line of Javascript and I still cannot figure out how to intercept the KML data or extract it from these maps (see below).

**Target Maps**

Here is an [Overlay](http://bit.ly/1lfvill) that consists of one Satellite footprint. 
and [Here](http://bit.ly/1SbXtMv) you can find much more examples of similar maps.

I am not even sure if this is possible and how it can be achieved. 
Has anyone been able to do a similar task ? Please I need guidance on how to achieve this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I take a look and tn the overlay there aren't data to scrap...

For the KML is simple you can do it server side.  opend then kml like an xml file and the scan  this dom for placemark, polygon and lineaRing tag inside you find the coordinates  in lng, lat format..

Client side you can do this whit jquery loading the xml file and scan for node you need ...

The kml struct is standard...

```
<Document>
    <Folder>
        <name>Full Satellite Footprint - EIRP</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Atlantic Ocean EIRP 40dBW</name>
            <styleUrl>https://www.telesat.com/kml/TelesatKMLStyles.kml#coverageArea</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>36.826,55.201,0 37.0055090185901,55.2151134621769,0 36.8423211206917,55.6055987892911,0 36.5363438121321,56.3253739818074,0 36.2041398771245,57.1121727752464,0 35.6982976142624,58.2038341375218,0 35.4781980136987,58.66035224623429,0 35.2392363744069,59.1245171274041,0 34.991585220959,59.5937508918316,0 34.7381410580738,60.0586398991811,0 34.4948230756851,60.5170059779041,0 34.2134913653683,60.9937069314964,0 33.9399744247826,61.4547783456267,0 33.6430131750038
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I understand parsing a KML file is simple but the prob here is that I do not have any files at all. Only one ( posted above). All I have are the links to this third party website. I'd like to know if it is possible at all to extract this data from the live google maps ( links @ Target maps) ? If yes, where should I look into . Thanks

Comment: From a live google maps like the sample`overlay`  you provided  not. The data are load by a script dinamically generated... and i haven't find kml o other uselful  data

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**pjscrape.**](http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/).

It has a cool WebKit engine which can run the Javascript and render the page. Maybe that's the thing you're asking.